# How to create a dynamic counter for day , Hour , minute and second up to a particular date and time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Create a dynamic counter up to a particular date using javascript [Look like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU6hS.png)

Comment: You'll need to use javascript, html and css to make that work

Comment: the search term *html css circular progress* gets some great results that you can base your code on

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are looking for a countdown timer/coming soon timer. There are scripts and ready-to-use templates out there. For some detail on how to make this, look at some random tutorials like this -> https://frontend-tricks.com/2018/11/21/how-to-make-countdown-with-jquery/

Comment: absolutely nothing like what the question asks for, and it uses jqueery, which was not asked for at all

Comment: Take a look at the page first before commenting some nonsense. Besides, jQuery _is_ JavaScript (just extended) and just because it wasn't explicitly asked, it still can be useful.

Comment: jQuery is a library, not asked for, and is, in my opinion a dinosaur (old, slow and extinct) ... and the page you linked to does not have pretty circles like the question asked for - take a look at the question and linked image before posting a link to a dinosaur :p